# iOS - Share data(and updates of data) between a specific group of devices using the same app

Tags: ios, ios8, nsuserdefaults, keychain, ios8-share-extension

For a simple example, if an app can display photos and someone takes a new photo, then the other people who have the same app, in the same group(if its possible to group this way) that has been created beforehand, will get the update of the new photo - (the list of photos would change and the app would handle that accordingly) (and updated via a push notification or some other automatic 'update'). This would also be useful for also editing a photo and updating that and for others to get that update.

I am wondering what are the options available (iOS 8+ only solution for now) to:

1. Have someone download an app and "invite" others who have also downloaded the app to be a part of their group - so that they have receive any additions or updates to the app in the way that i have described. I would really really not want to have to know someone else's e-mail address for this. Looking for another option.
2. Sharing this data between group members (and this solution might depend on #1, I am not sure).

I have read on here solutions like NSUserDefaults or key-chain grouping but since we are talking images here and depending on #1 there might be other better solutions.

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at with NSUserDefaults or key-chain. I don't think those have much of anything to do with what you're trying to accomplish. The issue you're having isn't iOS specific but it is going to require you to write the logic to make it work. You're going to need to have some sort of backend to store images that also supports user accounts and manage the friendships yourself. As far as inviting goes, you can always use a share sheet. But the components you're talking about you aren't going to get for free you're going to need to write the code to support them.

Comment: so something like Core Data syncing with iCloud isn't going to be viable here? I was thinking that might be one way...

Comment: No. All of your users would have to have access to the documents which means they would all need to authenticate with the same Apple ID and password. Syncing documents with iCloud would work for one user across multiple devices but not across multiple users. Maybe check out parse to prototype and start trying to flesh out a bare-bones backend. That has the added benefit of integrating with Facebook which might solve your invite-friends problem as well.

Comment: ok thanks. It seems that CloudKit would provide syncing of data between not only one group of people but groups of groups running the same app but the data between these groups stay private. It makes sense to write a 'data-sharing' app for a client who wants to share data but what I am looking for is a way to have multiple clients run the same app but only share whats internal for them. Hope that makes sense. Currently reading on Parse

Comment: I think you can use Facebook's Parse SDK. Which has support for storing your objects in server. You can check it.